# How to hide existing windows server shares

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a need to hide shares on our server.  We've recently discovered the technique of naming a share with the dollar sign (`$`) suffix, but this would require renaming our existing shares and doing so on a large group of PCs and laptops.  We are hoping to find a setting we could activate on the server, similar to the samba project's `browseable=no` option (https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#BROWSEABLE)

Does anyone know how you can prevent shares on a server from being visible/browesable?

Comment: I think your right. Thanks for your help. Make this an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to add "$" to the end of the share to 'hide' it. There is no other way to do it BUT, **Group Policy (GP Preference, in particular)** can very easily map the drives without any downtime for your users. With GPP you get very granular control via OU, security groups, etc (all things that are a part of AD. That's why @duenni mentioned it). I would just do this during a maintenance window. If you just check all the shares and permissions to ensure they work, your users should not even notice.

Helpful link for drive mapping via GPP: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership/

Answer (score -1):

The direct answer to your question is: it's not possible to do this on a Windows Server.

> this would require renaming our existing shares and doing so on a large group of PCs and laptops

This indicates that you have to do this by hand which leads to other questions:
What are we talking about here? Why don't you use Active Directory for that?

Comment: We have a collection of shares on one or more file servers. Most users log in via terminal server and access a common folder which has shortcuts to these shares.  But some users have created shortcuts to these shares directly form their desktop and even on their laptops and PCs. Trying to deploy this non-disruptively is a challenge. I'm not sure how AD would help in this case.